# Spark job that writes into Cassandra hangs at the last stage

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am inserting 21 million records into a Cassandra table using Spark.  The spark job takes around an hour and inserts all the records successfully but hangs at the very last stage (62/63).

My Spark properties:

```
spark.driver.memory 10g
spark.executor.cores 1
spark.executor.instances 40
spark.executor.memory 4g
```

The line that inserts records into Cassandra and getting hung at the last stage-

```
raw_data_final.rdd.saveToCassandra("marketing_dev1", "offer_detail_11", writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.perRow("ttl")))
```

How can I make the spark job exit successfully without hanging at the last stage?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a data skewed problem. Please paste your code for further analysis.

Please check if there is any row gets inserted in Cassandra. I doubt there will be any insert happened.

Apart from that provide your sample data and check if you are giving any partitioning column which will evenly divide the data

Comment: It's resolved.  It was because of a record with null value for one of the key columns

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had a record with null value for one of the key columns.  After removing that record, my job succeeded.